# chrome desktop PWA launch failed and closed

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

The desktop PWA icon is installed successfully, but when I want to launch the app and click the icon, it flashed and closed. How to debug and what is the issue?

Comment: Make sure you uninstalled previous tests completely. Go to chrome://apps/ in the address bar, right-click on your Icon and select "Remove from Chrome..." and make sure you also select the option to "Also clear data..." in the dialogue that shows. Then reinstall and test again.

Comment: I had uninstalled completely